# How to change offset of matrix python numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, offset, diagonal

I would like to get a matrix in shape of 100x100 like this:

```
[-2,1,0,0]
[1,-2,1,0]
[0,1,-2,1]
[0,0,1,-2]
```

I started with creating the diagonal:

```
import numpy as np
diagonal= (100)
diagonal= np.full(diagonal, -2)
A100 = (100,100)
A100 = np.zeros(A100)
np.fill_diagonal(A100, diagonal)
```

Now for changing the offset I tried:

```
off1=(99)
off1=np.ones(off1)
off1=np.diagonal(A100, offset=1)
```

But this doesn`t work.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: `np.diagonal` is for extracting a diagonal, not constructing one.  `np.diagflat` creates an array.  `np.eye` also takes an offset.  `np.diag` can be used either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct the matrix from three identity matrices:

```
np.eye(100, k=1) + np.eye(100, k=-1) - 2 * np.eye(100)
```

P.S. This solution is 7x faster than the `scipy.sparse` solution.

Comment: Do you know why it is so much faster?

Comment: Sparse matrices are slow by design.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`scipy.sparse.diags`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.diags.html)

```
from scipy.sparse import diags
A100 = diags([-2, 1, 1], [0, -1, 1], shape = (100, 100))
A100.A

Out[]: 
array([[-2.,  1.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1., -2.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1., -2., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       ...,
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ..., -2.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  1., -2.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  1., -2.]])
```